# How to set parameters for hiveQL queries

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I am running the following hiveql file with the following content

```
set mapred.output.compress=true;
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
set io.compression.codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '${hivevar:hadoop_temp_output_dir}${hivevar:filepattern}${hivevar:business_date}'  select data,'~','~${hivevar:src_sys_file_nm}~${hivevar:outbound_file_nm}~${hivevar:prd_typ_cd}~${hivevar:brnch_cd}~${hivevar:orig_src_sys}~${hivevar:my_src_sys}~${hivevar:extract_ts}~$hivevar:business_date}' from mydb.${hivevar:data_table} where src_sys_file_nm=${hivevar:src_sys_file_nm} and business_date=${hivevar:business_date};
```

In this example except data column in select query, everything else is in argument variable. Also I am just appending some strings like this `-- '~${hivevar:src_sys_file_nm}~${hivevar:outbound_file_nm}~${hivevar:prd_typ_cd}~${hivevar:brnch_cd}~${hivevar:orig_src_sys}~${hivevar:my_src_sys}~${hivevar:extract_ts}~$hivevar:business_date}'--` :

these are not table columns; they are some strings I am passing. This query works very well outside of Hive QL. When I execute the above HQL script, I am getting the following error :

> Invalid table alias or column reference 'somestring': (possible column names are: data, business_date, src_sys_file_nm, prd_typ_cd)

Note: business_date, src_sys_file_nm, prd_typ_cd are partitions.

It would be great if any could suggest/point out the mistake I have made here

Comment: Where are you passing those variables in from?

Comment: Passing through shell script variables

Comment: I am passing it through shell script variables